# Application.Restart ruins my settings

Tags: c#, application-restart

I am working on a project (simple phonebook) for personal use. It has got an option to be customised a bit (changing forms' icons, buttons' images, pictureboxes' images etc.) This works in the following way:

When the app is started, it checks which theme is chosen:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings f2 = new Settings();
        ThemeCheck();
    }
```

...where ThemeCheck() is:

```
void ThemeCheck()
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "Purple")
        {
            foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
            {
                form.Icon = Properties.Resources.Purple;
            }
            Main f1 = (Main)Application.OpenForms["Main"];
            Settings f2 = (Settings)Application.OpenForms["Settings"];
            f1.btn_Exit.Image = Properties.Resources.EXIT_purple;
        }
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "Blue")
        {
            foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
            {
                form.Icon = Properties.Resources.Blue;
            }
            Main f1 = (Main)Application.OpenForms["Main"];
            Settings f2 = (Settings)Application.OpenForms["Settings"];
            f1.btn_Exit.Image = Properties.Resources.EXIT_blue;
        }
    }
```

...etc, for each color (there are 10 different colors), it would be too long to copy the whole code here.

Nevertheless, I have managed to change themes successfully but when I restart the application, it switches to a random theme (always blue - maybe because it is the first one).

Is there a way how can I handle this? I would like the chosen theme to be set even after restarting the app. Basically, if purple theme was chosen, I would like it to remain purple after the restart as well.

I have uploaded the whole code here separated in two txt files (both forms - the main one (Form1) and the one where settings are configured (Form2)), if someone wants to have a look at it:

**Form1**: http://www.sendspace.com/file/jerayu

**Form2**: http://www.sendspace.com/file/p5twne

Comment: When do you call Save()?  If you never do that before calling Application.Start() then you just restart without saved settings.

Comment: I do call Save(), when I finish configuring settings (when form Settings is closed). I even tried double saving (saving when form Main closes) as well, but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist outside of the application proccess. This could be done with a application setting, resource file, or some kind of config file (xml,inf).

Hope this guides you.

-M